# how can asn1 notation and libraries help me?

Tags: network-programming, network-protocols

Abstract Syntax Notation

I'm in the process of writing a network client and server, in the process of research i came across asn1 notation.

How does asn1 notation help me program network services and what problems does it solve? Is it worth using? does it simplify network programming, or is it something i can do without? Are there alternatives?

I'm looking for tutorials on asn1, how and why i should implement it? Are you using it? If so, how are you using it.

Comment: It's a binary serialization format. You'd use it for the same sort of things you use XML for, or to interoperate with ASN.1 based services such as X.500 DAP.

Comment: @user499211: have you decided to use asn.1? I have the exactly same questions. What have you found out? Please share!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not implement ASN.1, (unless that is explicitly your goal).
Rather, most ASN.1 users find a library and use the library.
(in my experience, any library that is good also costs serious money).

I would not use ASN.1 unless you need to.  Interoperating with something that already specifies ASN.1 is a good reason to use it.  (example: I think that Kerberos transactions are encoded in ASN.1)  Otherwise, I'd look at any other format, such as XML or JSON.

Comment: ASN.1 is horrible. It is hard to imagine anything worse.

Comment: LOL @GregS.... it is very good at the specific task it was created for: to express limited data in an extremely precise, unambiguous, and efficient way.  Given that at the time it was created, 2400bd modems were "cutting edge" and ASCII was not universal, I understand why it is that way.  Still, on modern systems, there is less and less need for it, and popular sentiment is with you.